# Erro no Android Device Monitor do Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Após apanhar muito pra ter meu aparelho reconhecido pelo Android studio pra conseguir rodar nele o que eu tava programando, eu consegui, mas então o android studio quis que eu instalasse algo do android 7 que eu não vi direito pra habilitar o Instant Run. Eu fiz isso, e agora o aparelho não aparece mais quando dou run por nada, já tentei em MTP, PTP, colocar o aparelho com o programa fechado, já aberto, reiniciar tudo, só não tentei reinstalar o Android studio....
Ai pensei em ir ver se o aparelho aparecia no Monitor... mas recebo um caminho pra esse log:

```
!SESSION 2017-09-02 16:35:41.445 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.8.0_112-release
java.vendor=JetBrains s.r.o
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=pt_BR
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -data @noDefault

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.146
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609/@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.177
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201205150955.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.188
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.apache.lucene.core_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.532
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.base_3.6.101.v201302041200.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.536
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.ui_3.5.201.v20130108-092756.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.540
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.6.101.v20130116-182509.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.558
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.jetty.server_8.1.3.v20120522.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.605
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.platform.doc.user_4.2.2.v20130121-200410.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.614
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.core_3.6.100.v20120524-0627.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.617
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.team.ui_3.6.201.v20130125-135424.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.624
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:44.638
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:org.eclipse.ui.intro_3.4.200.v20120521-2344.jar@4 not found.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.137
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.142
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.143
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.144
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.144
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.144
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.144
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.145
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.146
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.146
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.148
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.148
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.149
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.150
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.150
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.150
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.151
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.157
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.158
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.159
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.159
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.306
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.306
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene_2.9.1.v201101211721 [25] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.306
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.highlighter_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.memory_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.queries_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.snowball_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.spellchecker_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.apache.lucene.misc_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Bundle org.apache.lucene.analysis_2.9.1.v201101211721 [26] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.apache.lucene.analysis 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.307
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.apache.lucene.core_[2.9.1,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.308
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.0.1.v20121109-203239 [90] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.308
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.308
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.308
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.308
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_[8.0.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.400.v20120912-130548 [93] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.apache.jasper.servlet_[0.0.0,6.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.309
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20120912-130548 [94] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.security_8.1.3.v20120522 [137] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.security 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_8.1.3.v20120522 [138] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.310
!MESSAGE Missing optionally imported package org.eclipse.jetty.jmx_8.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.security_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.session_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jetty.servlet 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ssl_[8.1.0,9.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_3.7.0.v20120523-1543 [146] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.core_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.team.ui_[3.4.100,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.311
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.platform_4.2.2.v201302041200 [149] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Missing optionally required bundle org.eclipse.ui.cheatsheets_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.platform 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.search_3.8.0.v20120523-1540 [151] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.search 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal_3.2.600.v20120912-155524 [163] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.intro_[3.4.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.312
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources_3.4.400.v20120705-114010 [165] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources 2 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.313
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring_[3.5.0,4.0.0).

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2017-09-02 16:35:49.319
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Aline%20Malheiro\.android\monitor-workspace\.metadata" is read-only.
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.lock(BasicLocation.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.BasicLocation.set(BasicLocation.java:137)
    at com.android.ide.eclipse.monitor.MonitorApplication.start(MonitorApplication.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

E eu não entendo nada de logs e queria uma luz.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo,no seu log aparece uma Exception que diz assim:
java.io.IOException: The folder "C:\Users\Aline%20Malheiro.android\monitor-workspace.metadata" is read-only.

Quando trabalhamos com java.io, diversos métodos lançam IOException, que é uma exception do tipo checked - o que nos obriga a tratá-la ou declará-la. Caso a exception ocorra, a JVM vai parar, mostrando a stacktrace.

Tente verificar as configurações nesse diretório, workspace, permissões etc